# Bower install chartjs - bower invalid-meta Chart.js is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json

Tags: bower, bower-install

Im trying to install chartjs with bower. The command i was using is

```
bower install --save chartjs
```

Im getting the following reply:

```
bower not-cached    https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js.git#*
bower resolve       https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js.git#*
bower checkout      chartjs#2.0.2
bower invalid-meta  Chart.js is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower resolved      https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js.git#2.0.2
```

I also tried using -F but it did nothing.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its solved. I just had a bug where the directory did not show the chartjs folder.